# Texts on visualizing big data

Tags: data-visualization, references, large-data, high-dimensional

I am looking for textbooks, papers or alternative material focusing on ideas and general principles for visualizing big data. By *big data* I primarily mean *wide data*, i.e. high-dimensional data, but I would also be interested in *tall data*, i.e. large sample sizes.

While classical works on data visualization are indispensible, I believe qualitatively new approaches are needed for *wide data* where the information content is pretty large (univariate visualizations alone take a lot of time to process, not to mention bivariate and multivariate relationships waiting to be explored). Whether new techniques are needed for *tall data* as well I am not sure about, but I would be interested in learning some perspectives on that, too.

Comment: Have you read some of the seminal texts on visualization in general, and found them lacking in applying to your wide and tall data? Eg, works by Edward Tufte (particularly *The Visual Display of Quantitative Information*) and Stephen Few

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett, I am aware of these works, and I find them enlightening. Thank you for the references! I like Cleveland's works as well. However, in wide data we have so much content to display that classical visualizations would take too much time and effort to process (by a human inspecting the visualizations) and a qualitatively new approach is needed.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions then for a textbook. Technology like Tableau, R Shiny, etc. that allow you to quickly change features and dimensions are what I see being used to create interactive, digital visualizations. I'm assuming you're thinking about static (could be printed on a sheet of paper) visualizations?

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett, I would be after whatever works best. If dynamic visualizations are more convenient, then let us use them.

Comment: How about dimension reduction like PCA, MDS, multidimensional unfolding? Those techniques can be used to display as much variability in two dimensions in the data as possible

Comment: @FransRodenburg, Thank you, I have not considered that. I wonder how informative they are w.r.t. visualizing patterns in the original variables which could be of central interest.

Comment: That depends on what kind of patterns you hope to find and what kind of data we're talking about. But if there are some presumed groups or clusters of variables in the data, than these dimension reduction techniques can sometimes help find them. At least it never hurts to have a look at some (visual) summary of your data.

Comment: @FransRodenburg, you are right. I should give it some more thought.